# Does this conformal map really map a semi-inf strip to union of two circles and half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

sorry for a long question just didn't know what exaclty to ask.
I'd like to have some verification of a little conformal map i've jsut constructed. I have a semi infinite strip {Im(z)<0, |Re(z)| < a/2} and have used the mobius transform f(z) = 1/z on it. This transform maps the real line to real line and the lines Im(z) = -+ a/2 to circles |z-+1/a| = 1/a. Is this correct? 
And does this mean it maps the whole strip to the area that is a union of those circles and upper half plane? (Since it maps 5i to -i/5, being below real line and outside either of the circles).

Side question in case someone knows: This is a physics exercise in finding a potential near the strip. Would there be an easier geometry to map the strip to for solving the exercise?

Comment: What you need to get a feel for is how the coordinate grid is transformed by $z \mapsto 1/z$. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY) that may help you visualise Möbius transformations. (And if not, at least you should find the backing music from Schumann's Kinderszenen very relaxing $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: Loved the video, thanks for it! While it helps a bit with seeing what 1/z does to the point in the plane Im still not sure about my question and my given anwer. Do you know the answer to that too?

Comment: It's a union of lots of half-circles: remember you haven't got any points with $\Im(z) \ge 0$ in your strip, but you do have all those vertical half-lines with $\Im(z) < 0$ for each value of $\Re(z)$ with $-a/2 <\Re(z) < a/2$. Draw the images of those half-lines. (Sorry for the fraktur: MathJax must like Schumann too.)

Comment: That makes sense. For some reason I thought the general idea you go by when dealing with conformal maps is just looking at what boundaries of the are you want to map map to(part of real line and 2 half circles in this case right?) and then figuring out on which side of those boundaries the area mapped to(ie outside or inside of the circle). Is that approach wrong, since it obviously doesnt produce those many half circles you are describing?

Comment: You can indeed work it out it by looking at the boundaries of the strip and thinking about the region those boundaries must enclose.  They will enclose all those half-circles. However the result won't be the union of a half-plane and two circles that you propose as the answer in your question. You weren't identifying the boundaries correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help first by the way! Where is my problem with wrong identification of boundaries besides not including the fact that the strip only includes Im(z)<0? Wouldn't a 3 line boundary still map into a 3 line/circles boundary?